# Customize Highcharts xaxis label

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, label

Can I create a chart like this with Highcharts?
[Expect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYN84.png)

Actually I did some similar thing with Highcharts by myself, but I got a problem when I Customize Highcharts xaxis label, can any one help me on that part?

```js
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['VISIONLINK', 'PRODUCT LINK WEB', 'CAT DAILY', 'NOT CONNECTED'],
            title: {
                text: null
            },
        lineColor: 'transparent',
            minorTickLength: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
          labels: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<strong class="hc-label">' + this.value + '</strong>';
            }
        }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: null,
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false,
            },

            minorTickLength: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
            gridLineColor: 'transparent',
           
            
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'right',
                    color:'black',
                    x: 30
                }
            },
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                pointWidth: 50,
                pointPadding: 0,

            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled:false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            
            name: 'VISIONLINK',
            data: [20,null,null,null]
        }, {
            
            name: 'PRODUCT LINK WEB',
            data: [null,40,null,null]
        }, {
            
            name: 'CAT DAILY',
            data: [null,null,200,null]
        },
         {
            name: 'NOT CONNECTED',
            data: [null,null,null,40]
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
.hc-label {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

See my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g3asmfj7/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is achievable, but I think that mocking the labels with the second series might be a easier than customizing the axis labels directly.

Configuration for the series which imitates labels is as follows:

```
, {
  color: '#efefef',
  enableMouseTracking: false,
  showInLegend: false,
  data: [
    ['VISIONLINK', 50],
    ['PRODUCT LINK WEB', 50],
    ['CAT DAILY', 50],
    ['NOT CONNECTED', 50]
  ],
  dataLabels: {
    format: '{key}'
  }
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/g3asmfj7/3/